# JavaScript namespacing and object creation

Tags: javascript, object, namespaces

I'm trying to figure out why you might use the following code:

```
    var myObject = myObject || {};
```

I've seen this used several times, but don't understand why this would be necessary. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Is there anything still unclear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People call JavaScript's binary or `||` the defaulting operator

```
var myObject = myObject || function(){};
```

is the same as

```
var myObject = myObject ? myObject : function(){};
```

The following code

```
var AppSpace = AppSpace || {};
```

is used because multiple files are going to set and use the namespace, and you don't want to overwrite the namespace if it has already been created. That way, it doesn't matter which file is included first.

Here's another example of defaulting.

```
function doSomething (callback)  {
   something();
   code();      
   callback = callback || function() {};
   // Now we can call the callback even if it wasn't passed in.
   callback();         
}
```

However, be careful of the following problem [Why does IE nuke window.ABC variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606847/why-does-ie-nuke-window-abc-variables/4607721#4607721)

That is if a namespace has been defined using

```
window.AppSpace = {a: 1};
```

And another file sets

```
var AppSpace = AppSpace || {}
```

In IE, it will overwrite the value of window.AppSpace to the empty object if the two scripts are in different script tags because of variable hoisting and the fact that IE doesn't realize that `window.a` and `var a` at the top level are all pointing at the same variable.

Comment: http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/ This is what I'm wondering about. Why even check, if you want your object to equal your function or the class.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté  C family? I didn't think so, in C, `||` always returns a boolean. It's usually true in loosely typed languages

Comment: Let me revise it while I compile a C program. `=]`

Comment: Yes, that pesky C won't support cool things. `:(` I should've worded it *C-derived* languages as JS (broad C family) and PHP (written in C).

Comment: PHP doesn't do it either.  It always returns a boolean.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Not your day :) `echo  0 || 'Hello World';` outputs `1`  in PHP

Comment: Removed first comment, yes my bad, I always use ternaries in PHP.. I should sleep at night more often.

Comment: In PHP you can use the ternary shorthand to mimic that behavior though - `$foo = $foo ?: 'default';`. Alright time to work a bit more until I start breaking all the PHPs. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Sure you can, but it doesn't look nearly as cool, you can do that in any language with casting and void pointers.

Comment: True that. Nothing as hackish yet elegant as that. You can even put expressions inside of it: `var myObject; myObject || (myObject = {});` - even though slightly less readable, theoretically it should have a better performance as it doesn't perform an assignment if the value is already truthy.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I can't stand premature optimization, specially at the cost of readability, sorry.

Comment: Both ways have the same level of readability for me, of course, that depends on your group's code style guidelines.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté You cannot say that an assignment inside of a boolean expression has the same level of readability as not having one

Comment: The code I write usually comes from [this](http://i.imgur.com/hU1Gn.png) to something [slightly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12521126/1331430) more complex when it is about JS, assignments and expressions inside control flow statements are a very trivial thing for me (yes I'm different). `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I'm glad I don't have to read code you write. You should write code for others to read. More than 99% don't like that style (specially a gigantic hard to understand boolean expression). When you do that kind of thing, you're pissing off the next developer.

Comment: I understand your point, that's why I hardly ever contribute to open-source projects (except when I find a bug that needs fixing). Thankfully, in the projects I code for, I'm the one responsible for maintaining the code - and usually there's much worse pieces of code from other parties. But from a neutral view point, I do not use as much bitwise operators and hex numbers instead of decimals as many devs do.

Answer (score 2):

function(){} is an empty class since classes are functions in JavaScript.  This code in particular is taking advantage of the early-exit from OR in JavaScript - it evaluates the first item, and sets the result equal to that if it's truthy and equal to the second item if it's falsy.  So if myObject is truthy (not null), myObject equals that, and if it's not then it equals an empty function.

Basically, what this code is saying is "if myObject is already something, leave it where it is, and otherwise make it equal to this blank function".

Comment: Does this help you, or were you more wondering about the function(){} part on a conceptual level?

Comment: Andrew, thanks. I get that, but if the function was filled with properties and methods, why would you want to not overwrite the current myObject if it already exists. What is the benefit of checking if it exists if you want myObject to equal your constructor.

Comment: What do you mean, myObject equal to your constructor?  If you mean function(){}, that isn't a constructor, it's a blank object.
Basically, myObject could be undefined, and we'd rather it be a blank object if that's the case.  If it's not null, then we'd like to leave it the way it is.  This code would be used in a place where it might be hit more than once, or where myObject might already exist.  There are a lot of reasons to set it equal to a blank object instead of undefined - for instance, so that later on you can add methods/properties to it, which would be a problem if it were undefined.

Comment: Every function is a constructor, if called with `new`

Comment: If you say var Obj = Obj || {}; Then, go on to define Obj as a constructor of a class or a fucntion. Why check if it exists? Why not just define it the way you want to without the check?

Comment: @user699242 See my answer for the explanation

Comment: Given the edit made to the question, Juan Mendes' answer is better and I think he explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

This technique is called "Short-circuit" evaluation.

*hort-circuit evaluation, minimal evaluation, or McCarthy evaluation denotes the semantics of some Boolean operators in some programming languages in which the second argument is only executed or evaluated if the first argument does not suffice to determine the value of the expression: when the first argument of the AND function evaluates to false, the overall value must be false; and when the first argument of the OR function evaluates to true, the overall value must be true*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Well, in JS it's more than shorting the evaluation, it actually returns the value where the evalued stopped.