# Converting nested html to bbCode quote tags

Tags: jquery, bbcode

I am trying to convert the following html

```
<div class="bbQuote">
    <div class="quoteAuthor">Joe Block</div>
    <div class="quoteContent">This is the first message<br>
        <div class="bbQuote">
            <div class="quoteAuthor">Jane Doe</div>
            <div class="quoteContent">This is the second message</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

to the following bbCode

```
[quote=Joe Block]
    This is the first message
    [quote=Jane Doe]
        This is the second message
    [/quote]
[/quote]
```

How can I do this using jQuery?

PS: Nested HTML can have zero or more children

Comment: The HTML is in the page or a string? In the page I believe?

Comment: HTML is parsed using `jQuery('#commentContent').html()` so it can be html or text.

Comment: I made a primitive example of what you want - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/tE77x/) but 1. It won't convert other bbCode tags ([b], [i], anchor tags etc), 2. Indentation is not identical. I'd use ajax to fetch the actual post content from the DB or use a proper jQuery bbCode parsing library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very basic example:

```
var html = $('#commentContent').html(),
    beingParsed = $('<div>' + html.replace(/<br>/g, '\n\r') + '</div>'),
    $quote;
while (($quote = beingParsed.find('.bbQuote:first')).length) {
    var $author = $quote.find('.quoteAuthor:first'),
        $content = $quote.find('.quoteContent:first'),
        toIndent = $author[0].previousSibling;

    toIndent.textContent = toIndent.textContent.substring(0, toIndent.textContent.length-4);
    $author.replaceWith('[quote=' + $author.text() + ']');
    $content.replaceWith($content.html());
    $quote.replaceWith($quote.html() + '[/quote]');
}

var parsedData = beingParsed.html();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tE77x/3/)

**Limitations:**

1. It won't convert other HTML to BBCode (`<b>`, `<i>`, anchor tags etc);
2. Indentation/white space is not 100% accurate.

I'd use Ajax to fetch the actual post content from the DB or use a proper jQuery bbCode parsing library.