# Javascript variable or new function causing errors in IE

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I'm having an issue with this statement in Internet Explorer,
I was wondering if there is a saner way to do it?

```
var NEWVARIABLE = NEWVARIABLE || {};
NEWVARIABLE.Tools = NEWVARIABLE.Tools || {};
```

Its giving me the error that `NEWVARIABLE` does not exist

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard This is creating a namespace, makes perfect sense, you've just never seen this

Comment: May be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606847/why-does-ie-nuke-window-abc-variables/4607721#4607721

Comment: There is nothing syntactically or functionally wrong with that code, what is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've accepted an answer, but it contains a misleading statement:

> You cannot use (or test) a variable that's not been defined. That's what you're doing

The variable is declared, so it isn't what you are doing.

In the OP, the code:

```
> var NEWVARIABLE = NEWVARIABLE || {};
> NEWVARIABLE.Tools = NEWVARIABLE.Tools || {};
```

contains no syntax errors, the only case where it will throw an error is if NEWVARIABLE already exists and has a Tools property that throws an error when attempting to access or assign to it (as may happen with certain host objects).

If `NEWVARIABLE` has previously been assigned a native object or primitive value, it will not throw an error, though the result may not be what you expect.

Comment: @ehime I know that my answer did not address the question, but I don't see how this answers the question either. It just explains what was wrong with my question and doesn't suggest what the OP needs to do to solve it? ehime, what was your final solution?

Comment: @JuanMendes—I was pointing out that there is insufficient information in the OP to provide a definitive answer, hence an explanation of why the error might occur as a hint as to what to look for in trying to fix it.

Comment: I understood what you did, I'm just trying to understand why the OP thinks this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use (or test) a variable that's not been defined. I originally thought that's what you were doing with the following statement

```
var NEWVARIABLE = NEWVARIABLE || {};
```

However, thanks to Fabrício, I realized that the var declaration  gets hoisted (moved to the top of the script tag and is therefore already declared when it hits the statement.

The less confusing way to test if a variable is to use `typeof === 'undefined'` to see if a variable exists

```
var NEWVARIABLE;
if (typeof NEWVARIABLE === 'undefined') {
    NEWVARIABLE = {};
}
```

You can use the same style when checking for properties, you don't have to use `typeof` test for properties, you are allowed to test them even if they aren't defined.

Comment: if NEWVARIABLE is undefined, NEWVARIABLE is construct as a new object no ?

Comment: @My_Boon You are using it by running the if test, you're not allowed to try to read from an undefined variable

Comment: AFAIK, in case the variable is not defined yet, `var` declarations are hoisted up to the top of the scope and have the native value `undefined` until the assignment is reached at runtime. Seems to work on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pMQJ/).

Comment: Indeed, I've always makes like that

Comment: @FabrícioMatté But if there was already a NEWVARIABLE defined by a previous script, your code would overwrite it.

Comment: Well that depends on the scope. If it is in the same scope, it'd be assigned to the same value. If it's an outer scope then yes, it'd overwrite it and your answer is a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: Here's commented [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pMQJ/5/), +1 for the extra cautiousness.

Comment: Thanks for the lightening fast answer +1 @JuanMendes

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I would have expected the hoisted var statement to reset the variable to undefined, but it doesn't, so your comment makes a lot of sense. If the statement is in an innder scope, then you would have to use `window.NEWVARIABLE` anyway, I'm kind of confused... How is it that ehime is getting an error with his code, then?

Comment: The `var` declaration just tells the interpreter that the variable to be used belongs to that scope, so a var declared more than once in the same scope doesn't make any difference at runtime. JSLint (Crockford) recommends moving all var declarations to the top of the scope they belong to, possibly to avoid such confusions. And yes, `window.NEWVARIABLE` and `window['NEWVARIABLE']` would allow you to access the global scope's as variable and functions declared in the global scope are added as properties of the `window` object as you stated.

Comment: Now why it was returning an error on OP's code is beyond me, his question's code runs perfectly fine on IE9 - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJERn/). Possibly due to the scoping. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Actually,it could be the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606847/why-does-ie-nuke-window-abc-variables/4607721#4607721 which I answered, that is, the variable may have been created using `window.MYVAR` and later on (in a different script tag, still at global scope), then a hoisted var statement actually overwrites `window.MYVAR`, only in IE. But maybe not, my example would still have the hoisted variable...

Comment: Wow, JScript has way too many "peculiarities". I'll read it throughout. `=]`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code in that it does not contain any syntax errors and should run without error in any ECMAScript compliant user agent. The answer marked as correct is misleading, NEWVARIABLE is defined and therefore able to be tested per the OP. Once an object reference is assigned by the first line, then properties can be tested too. Whatever was causing the OP's error, it wasn't this code.

Comment: @RobG Just to be accurate, my comments do explain that I don't think my solution is fixing the OP's problem (at least the way I thought it would)

Comment: "**in any ECMAScript compliant user agent**", there is the problem, OP was asking specifically about IE. Juan's solution fixes it as per OP's feedback, so it's a correct answer IMO.

Comment: But yes, @RobG has a point, the answer's first statement is misleading as the variable is in fact declared.

Comment: @RobG and Fabrício, I've removed the erroneous statements from the answer, it's still a mistery how that solved the OP's problem. I wish the OP would show all the relevant code

Comment: @FabrícioMatté—IE is about as ECMAScript compliant as any other browser (W3C DOM compliance is another matter, but getting better). It certainly has a few quirks (as do others) but they aren't relevant here. @Juan—did a minor edit to keep the JSLint-ophiles happy. :-)

Comment: Yes, IE is getting better as in, IE10 has about as many features and compliance as Firefox 4 had, problem is, XP users are stuck with IE8 and odds are IE10 won't even be ported to Win7, so not only Microsoft is always a couple years behind but also IE users tend to get stuck in time due to these quirks. But that's talk for another topic. `=]`