# window.event is undefined only in IE after assigning

Tags: javascript, user-interface

```
newInvoker: function(src, action) {
        var srcWindowName = src.name;
        var rowActionTarget = this.event.target;
        return function(evt) {
            if (!evt) var evt = window.event;
            var win = window.frames["tableContentFrame"].frames[srcWindowName];
            win.event = rowActionTarget;
            win.eval(action);
            tvc.rowActionHandler.hideContainer();
            tvc.stopBubbleEvent(evt);
        };
    },
```

this code is working fine in Chrome and FF.
BUt in IE win.event is always undefined after i assign a value for it.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606847/why-does-ie-nuke-window-abc-variables) Might answer your question. IE has certain limitations which makes it less active on window objects. You have to take care of some script tags and scopes. The above link can help you find the solution to your problem.

Comment: got the answer!!

Just make win.event to win.target which will work in all the browser.